# error with query to get the statue of field from other table (join tables)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables the first called latestnews and second called language_latestnews

which `latestnews`has `latestnewsstatus and latestnewsid . 
and language_latestnews  has  latestnewsid

I need to show the only Active latestnewsstatus  , and here's my code in the api

```
 public function getlatest($select_values = "*", $table_name, $join_on = "", $language_id) {
    $join_table = "language_" . $table_name;
    $result = array();
    $this->db->select($select_values);
    $this->db->from($table_name);

    if ($table_name != "latestnews") {
        $this->db->where($table_name . ".featuredstatus","=", "Yes" );
    }
    $this->db->join($join_table, $table_name . "." . $join_on . "=" . $join_table . "." . $join_on, "left");
    $this->db->where($join_table . ".languageid", $language_id ,'latestnews.latestnewsstatus',"=","Active");
    $this->db->join('language_latestnews', 'language_latestnews.latestnewsid = latestnews.latestnewsid', 'left');
    $this->db->where('latestnewsid.latestnewsstatus', "Active");

    $this->db->limit("1");

    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

but it's give me Database error . Can you tell me what's wrong here :(

The error is :

> ## A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'latestnewsid.latestnewsstatus' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT `offers`.`offerid`, `offertitle`
>   FROM `offers`
>   LEFT JOIN `language_offers` ON `offers`.`offerid`=`language_offers`.`offerid`
>   LEFT JOIN `language_latestnews` ON `language_latestnews`.`latestnewsid` = `latestnews`.`latestnewsid`
>   WHERE `offers`.`featuredstatus` = '='
>   AND `language_offers`.`languageid` = '1'
>   AND `latestnewsid`.`latestnewsstatus` = 'Active'
>    LIMIT 1
>
> Filename: modules/api/models/Apimodel.php
>
> Line Number: 394

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It's giving me Database error

Comment: Paste the error code to?

Comment: It's api , I'm testing that with postman application . 
It's only give me Database error

Comment: I have updated the question please check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory **Unknown column 'latestnewsid.latestnewsstatus' in 'where clause'**. In your query there is no column with the name `latestnewsstatus` in `latestnewsid` table. So put the proper column name here and try again.